# Exclude LocalDate class for checking by SpotBugs plugin

Tags: spotbugs

I'm getting SpotBugs warning with code 'EI_EXPOSE_REP2' for class field

`private final LocalDate localDate`

I'm trying to exclude this check for `java.util.LocalDate` class for **whole app**.

I tried to use annotation `@SuppressFBWarnings("EI_EXPOSE_REP2")` and it works. But for me this is not good idea of adding this annotation into every place where `LocalDate` is used. Instead of that I would prefer to add this rule to *spotbugs-exclude.xml*. And I did so but it's not working (still getting SpotBugs warning). My *spotbugs-exclude.xml* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FindBugsFilter>
   <Match>
    <Class name="java.time.LocalDate" />
    <Bug code="EI_EXPOSE_REP2" />
  </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

pom.xml

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
  <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${spotbugs.mavenplugin.version}</version>
  <executions>
     <execution>
         <id>spotbugs-verify</id>
         <goals>
           <goal>check</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
     <excludeFilterFile>spotbugs-exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So my question: how could I exclude SpotBugs checking for specific class in whole app?

Additional question: could we mix up *spotbugs-exclude.xml* and annotations @SuppressFBWarnings inside the same app? Is SpotBugs able to recognize both configurations?

Answer (score 1):

I have done more investigations and found similar topic here: https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/issues/1601

So looks like for 4.3.0 version SpotBugs plugin has buggy behavior with checking immutable classes and provide warning EI_EXPOSE_REP and EI_EXPOSE_REP2.

So my decision: **migrate from 4.3.0 to 4.2.3** - currently all works.